# Dowload Table in Excel via Power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to download this table in Excel

https://infogram.com/a-energy-suppliers-hedging-table-1hdw2jpg7n8xj2l

via Power Query and make an automatic update connection. But for some reason it does not work because it does not recognize the table as such. I do not know why any suggestion?

Thx

Comment: You need it connected live? If no, you can copy the dataset from page source and parse it as JSON...

Comment: I just need to be able to press the refresh button in excel and then have a refreshed version of the data in my corresponding excelsheet

Comment: It going to be complex, please read this topic:
https://datachant.com/2017/03/30/web-scraping-power-bi-excel-power-query/